# Git rebase clarifications

Tags: git, rebase

I've been experimenting with git for a few weeks now, and while I'm pretty happy with what I can do with it now, there's still some behaviors I can't really explain concerning rebase.

I found this image which seems great to understand this concept:

[image]

But I can't really seem to get it working this way; Here's what i did:

I created a file.txt in a folder, git inited it, and committed it. then I added one line 'one', commit, new line 'two' commit, 'three'...

Then I created a new branch 'feature', added five and six.

and now if I use git checkout master, git rebase feature, things work like on the picture above.

But then i decided to reset and do an interactive rebase instead:

git rebase -i feature: and in nano all I have is noop instead of my commit list..? If go through with it it still works the same, but why can't I decide to reword/pick/skip commits in that case?

now if I reset and do a merge instead, I see no difference:

---- merge ----

```
(on master)
git merge feature

$ git log --oneline --all
ec382b3 (HEAD -> master, feature) five
d32ed5c four
1499f19 three
24f93bc two
544c929 one
c78eaba first push

$ git branch -a -v
  feature ec382b3 five
* master  ec382b3 five
```

---- rebase ----

```
(on master)
git rebase feature

$ git log --oneline --all
ec382b3 (HEAD -> master, feature) five
d32ed5c four
1499f19 three
24f93bc two
544c929 one
c78eaba first push

$ git branch -a -v
  feature ec382b3 five
* master  ec382b3 five
```

Last but not least, if I rebase feature on top of master and then

```
$git rebase -i HEAD~3

pick 1499f19 three
pick d32ed5c four
pick ec382b3 five
```

great, I can pick my commits or erase them to skip them, BUT, remember there's one line per commit, let's say I want to skip the fourth line/commit:

Conflict:

```
one
two
three
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
four
five
>>>>>>> ec382b3... five
```

First how come this is a conflict? the previous commits had

```
one
two
three
```

so there's no conflict to have, the head has nothing indeed,
but more importantly, even though four and five are separate commit, four still shows after I removed its commit? I thought git saved changes and not the whole file...?

That's the few behaviors I don't understand, thanks.

Comment: Your merge was a "fast-forward" (not a true merge). Use `git merge --no-ff` to force a true merge. Add `--graph`, i.e., `git log --graph --oneline`, to get Git to draw the graph too. Note that when `git log` could display either parent of a merge, the process of walking through the two divergent sets of commits gets more complicated. When there is a simple linear chain, `git log` must show it in the linear-chain order.

Comment: As for: *I thought git saved changes and not the whole file...?* That's completely wrong: each commit is a whole-file save (of every file!). Copying a commit (as rebase does—note that the hash IDs of the new commits are different!) involves turning the snapshot *into* a change, which Git does by comparing the snapshot with its immediate parent snapshot. (Git does use a bunch of tricks to save disk space, including the fact that each saved file is read-only, so if this one is the same as last time, we can just *re-use* the previous save.)

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense. And what about the noop?

Comment: After a fast-forward merge, both branch names point to the same tip commit. So `git rebase -i feature` lists the commits that are on/in `master` that aren't on/in `feature`, which is no commits at all. Those are the commits to be copied. Rebase needs a non-empty instruction sheet (an empty one makes it abort) so it writes `noop` in as the one instruction: copy no commits, then finish the rebase operation.

Answer (score 2):

The conflict is because you are writing stuff *at the end of the file* on each commit.... that makes it tricky for git when you cherry-pick (the basis for rebase). Try doing the same operations but in the middle of the file (make it, 20 lines.. work around line 11) and then it won't fail.